# Got Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError while using Ruby to upload file to S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am following the tutorial here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html
to learn about using Ruby to upload file to S3, I wrote this:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  access_key_id: '.......',
  secret_access_key: '........'
)

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-east-1')
obj = s3.bucket('aws-adms-whitelisting-rules').object('test')
obj.upload_file('~/Desktop/ruby/test.rb')
```

But got following error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.10.7/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/regional_endpoint.rb:34:in `after_initialize': missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION'] (Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.10.7/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:84:in `block in after_initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.10.7/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:83:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.10.7/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:83:in `after_initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.10.7/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:21:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.10.7/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:105:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.10.7/lib/aws-sdk-resources/resource.rb:169:in `extract_client'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.10.7/lib/aws-sdk-resources/resource.rb:15:in `initialize'
    from test.rb:35:in `new'
    from test.rb:35:in `<main>'
```

Could you show me a path forward? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more standard way to do this would be to pass the region as an argument to the instance of `Aws::S3::Client` you create.

You can then just pass the instance of `Aws::S3::Client`([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html)) to the `Aws::S3::Resource`([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Resource.html)) you're creating.

**For example:**

```
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  region: 'us-east-1',
  access_key_id: '.......',
  secret_access_key: '........'
)

resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: s3)
obj = resource.bucket('aws-adms-whitelisting-rules').object('test')
obj.upload_file('~/Desktop/ruby/test.rb')
```

Comment: I believe the `Aws::S3::Client` object must be passed in as a keyword argument to the `Aws::S3::Resource` since the `#initialize` only accepts an options hash.

Comment: @dlachasse, good catch you're right. I've edited my answer. Try initializing the resource with a hash, let me know if that works.